# Ubuntu locked after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, reboot

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 a few hours ago. The system said I should reboot anytime. But I got no `y/n` question. So I left the terminal box and tried to restart the system. I was asked to type in my masterid password first. Clicking that button did not work. I could only click the cancel button. I managed to close the system though. After restart, the system gave error messages like:

- Autofs4 not implemented
- Starting of arbitrary automount point
  unsupported
  And then I get the start screen with the names of the two Ubuntu users; but in a basic Ubuntu 20.04 format. And I cannot use my mouse or keyboard to log in.

What should I do to get in and repair this?

Comment: Try booting into recovery mode. Does your keyboard work here?

Comment: I found out just that using my smartphone. I then could open a terminal mode and give the sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade etcetera. commands to repair the missing data. 99% of the upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 appeared to have been done already, so after a few minuten the system was up and running again.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer!